# What is the difference between 'to be' and 'for'?

Tags: prepositions, auxiliary-verbs

I have a question about 'to be' and 'for'.

> I drink water for healthy.

or

> I drink water to be healthy.

What's the difference between both?

Comment: This is not a for/to distinction in the manner asked about in [ELU's "for-to" tag](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/to-for). As such I think ELL is a better site to answer the question.

Comment: "For healthy" is impossible because "for" is a preposition that requires a noun object, but "healthy" is an adjective, not a noun

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is that only one of them is correct English, but with a small change we can get two correct sentences:

> I drink water for health.

and

> I drink water to be healthy.

The first sentence uses "for" with the *noun*, "health"; the second uses "to be" with the *adjective*, "healthy".

Both mean roughly the same thing.